# I am trying to store the values of a complex checkbox form in mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have a multi-part html form and I want to send the data gotten from this form to the database. My issue is with the second step of the form where there are multiple tabs with multiple checkboxes. I am totally confused how to create the schema of this form because of the multiple tabs and many checkboxes. How can I successfully insert the quantity and item name of every category in a well ordered manner that it will be easy for me to get all the records of each entry? Each of the sections have ID (1 to 4) and each item have an itemid.

Here is a link to the form(just for clearity of what I mean. check the step 2 of the form).
http://www.diggysmoving.com/get-free-quotes.php

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `moving_entries` (
  `moving_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `moving_from` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `moving_to` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type_from` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type_to` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `living_room_items` text NOT NULL,
  `bedroom_items` text NOT NULL,
  `kichen_items` text NOT NULL,
  `other_items` text NOT NULL,
  `additional_items` text NOT NULL,
  `required _services` text NOT NULL,
  `move_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `referral_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `special_instruction` text NOT NULL,
  `created` date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`moving_id`);
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and below is part of the html code

```
<tr id="id-inverter4">
  <td class="timesTData text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="15%">
     <span class="opening" style="visibility: hidden;">(</span>
     <span class="digit" style="visibility: hidden">1</span>
     <span class="fa fa-times" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
     <span class="closing" style="visibility: hidden">)</span>
   </td>
   <td class="nameTData" width="55%" style="vertical-align: middle">Inverter</td>
   <td class="minusTData text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="10%" id="ms-inverter4" data-id="id-inverter4">
     <span class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
   </td>
   <td class="plusTData text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="10%" id="ps-inverter4" data-id="id-inverter4">
     <span class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
   </td>
   <td class="checkTData" width="10%">
     <input type="checkbox" class="form-control checkBox inverter4" name="itemQuantities[]" title="Inverter" data-href="inverter4" data-tr="id-inverter4">
     <input type="checkbox" name="itemIds[]" class="inverter4" value="60" style="display: none;">
     <input type="checkbox" name="sectionIds[]" class="inverter4" value="4" style="display: none;">
   </td>
```

Comment: since their so many options for step 2 and is no limit of selecting i will separate them in different table where id of the row will be moving_id , later one i can easly match current moving and living room options

Comment: I tried creating different tables to hold the section id and the item id. But I am still stuck. I can't put it together in my head how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one general table that will hold moving_id , name , email, from , to ... and few separated tables that will hold the options , here is example of step2 Living Room , you can make same for bedroom , kitchen and other

```
CREATE TABLE `living_room` (
`moving_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`television` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tv_stand` int(11) NOT NULL,
`dvd` int(11) NOT NULL,
`decoder` int(11) NOT NULL,
`home_theatre` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subwoofers` int(11) NOT NULL,
`settee` int(11) NOT NULL,
`centre_table` int(11) NOT NULL,
`side_stool` int(11) NOT NULL,
`centr_rug` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here i set all options to (int) because are checkboxes so you can insert 1 or 0 if is checked or not 
moving_id here will be same as moving_id from your general table , than you can match easy selected options for current moving_id

Comment: Although this exactly did not work but along with your comment on the original question, I was able to come up with something. Thanks and for that I am marking your answer as correct

Comment: @Atoms i'm glad to help you